# Concept of Two-Way data binding in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, modelattribute, two-way-binding

This is my login.jsp file.

```
<form:form method="POST" action="checklogin" modelAttribute="log">

        <form:label path="username">UserName: </form:label> 
        <form:input path="username" id="username" /><br /><br />
        <br /> 
        <form:label path="pswd">Password: </form:label>
          
         <form:password path="pswd" id="password" /><br /> <br />
        <br /> 
        <input type="submit" id="btnLogin" value=login class="login" />
</form:form>
```

This is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checklogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String chklogin(@ModelAttribute Login login, Model mod) {    

        if (login.getUsername().equals("subro") && login.getpswd().equals("ss")) {
            mod.addAttribute("log",login);
            return "Home";
        }
        else {
            return "Login";
        }
    }
```

Still I am getting the error as
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'log' available as request attribute

Comment: Please anyone clarify my doubts as I am not able to understand the topic of two way binding.

Comment: IN your form you have `modelAttribute="log"` in your code you have `@ModelAttribute Login login`. So it is expected to be named `login` not `log` or specify the `name` attribute in `@ModelAttribute` to match the one from the form.

Comment: I have change modelAttribute="login" instead but still not working.

Comment: Because in the `@GetMapping` you are probably using the wrong name as well.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question multiple times!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
@ModelAttribute Login login
```

To

```
@ModelAttribute Login log
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Two way data binding in spring allows user inputs to be dynamically bound to the beans. It is two-way in a sense that it can get the inputs from the beans and it can post the user inputs to the beans using GET and POST api.

Using the `@ModelAttribute` annotation you can bind the user inputs with the beans.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String login(@ModelAttribute Login log){ //one-way binding
   return "Login";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/checklogin", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String chklogin(@ModelAttribute Login log, Model mod) {  //two-way binding

   if (login.getUsername().equals("subro") && login.getpswd().equals("ss")) {
       mod.addAttribute("log",login);
       return "Home";
   }
   else  return "Error";
        
}
```

Earlier I haven't written the login method which is mapped with the url `/login`.

When you are getting an error as "Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'log' available as request attribute", it means that the beans ('log' in my case) is not able to bind with the view page.